# I want to find the filesize in gcp using os.stat it does not work

Tags: google-cloud-platform

so I have been trying to find the size of files in gcp using os.stat(filename).st_size() .But it does not work . also I donot want to use the gcp bucket UI/Ux feature where u can see the size .

I have few doubts
do we need to use the filename or filepath
if I am using this function will it will be able to access the file .
is ghere any other way out for this to work .

Comment: Is it file in block storage (a persistent disk)? or is it an object in Cloud Storage?

Comment: its a file in a bucket in gcp .I habe tried the python function as stated above but it didnt worked out ,so now I am thinking of using blob.size function dont know whether it will work or not . but it will be good if we can do it using python libs @guillaumeblaquiere

Comment: You can't use os library which know only block storage files format with a remote and blob storage format. To know the size of the object, you have to get the metadata with and HTTP request, that your "os" lib can't do out of the box!